# Missing Environment Variables in VS Code Terminal Process

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, process, environment-variables

I have an environment variable called `DEBUG`, whose value is the string `"true"`. I'm reading this variable from within a Node process (itself a child process of `cmd.exe`) via `process.env.DEBUG`:

[image]

*Note: I am using *nvm* for Windows, and have tested versions 14.18.1 and 18.12.1 of Node. Both versions yielded the same results and experience.*

As you can see, this works as expected. Likewise, PowerShell also works as expected.

When testing the same scenario from within a terminal in VS Code, `undefined` is returned:

[image]

To simplify things, I have checked that no scripts are loaded which would remove the environment variable, no plugins are installed which would alter the variable, and no difference is made when using a different terminal within VS Code.

After running into a dead-end, I turned my attention to the process Environment, to see where the `DEBUG` variable may be getting dropped. To proceed, I used both Process Monitor, and Process Explorer. When I launch Visual Studio Code (from explorer.exe), I can confirm that it has the variable in its *Environment*.

The process tree of Code.exe instances and the inclusion of the `DEBUG` variable in their respective Environments is as follows:

| Process | Type | `DEBUG` Inclusion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code.exe | none/parent | true |
| › Code.exe | crashpad-handler | true |
| › Code.exe | gpu-process | true |
| › Code.exe | utility | true |
| › Code.exe | renderer | true |
| › Code.exe | renderer | true |
| › Code.exe | ptyHost | **false** |

As you can see, the variable is present in the environments of all child processes, with the exception of the `--type=ptyHost` child process. That process has a couple other runtime args (paths truncated):

```
"C:\…\Code.exe"
  --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node 
  "c:\…\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork"
  --type=ptyHost
  --logsPath C:\…\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20221230T172335
```

It is unclear to me why some environment variables are not present for the *ptyHost* process. In my frustration, I even created a second environment variable named `DEEBUG`, and it too was not present under the same circumstances.

I'm aware that alternative approaches would arguably be more ideal, such as using a tool like *dotenv*, but I also feel as though there is a valuable lesson just around the corner here for me.